# Unable to loop through mysql_insert_id() for multiple entries

Tags: php

I'm retrieving last id of tbl_orderdetail(table 1) in order to add addon items entries into tbl_orderdetail_addon(table 2). Basically it should insert into (table 2) as per the number of ids received from (table 1). I'm using mysql_insert_id() for that.

i'm getting that right but the ids are not looping through. It inserts the same id of  (table 1) for all entries in (table 2). Say that I have two entries in (table 1),obviously it should return 2 id's.And each id has 2 add on items .So in (table 2) there should be four entries with 2 different id's of (table 1). IN my case Im getting 4 entries of same id of (table 1).
Here's my coding:

```
$o_id_detail=mysql_insert_id();//(table 1) id
foreach($addon_price as $a_p=>$p)// 
     { 
         echo $a_p;
           foreach($p as $m)
              {

                 $addon_id= $m['id'];
                 echo $m['addon_name'];
                 echo $m['deposit'];
                 echo $m['ppd'];
                 echo $m['pp_eight'];
                 echo $m['pp_six'];


$addon_total=$m['deposit']+$m['ppd']+$m['pp_eight']+$m['pp_six'];
                 echo $addon_total;



                  $addon_detail="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail_addon (OrderID,addOns_id,addOns_price) VALUES ('$o_id_detail','$addon_id','$addon_total')";
                               if(!empty($addon_id))
                                {
                                  mysql_query($addon_detail)or die(mysql_error());


                                 }
                    }     

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically it should insert into (table 2) as per the number of ids received from (table 1)

`mysql_insert_id()` only returns a single `int` value.  As [described in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php):

> Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the
>   previous query (usually INSERT).

You need to insert the first row to table1 then the corresponding rows in table2; insert the second row to table1 then the corresponding rows in table2; etc.

**Pseudo-code** to explain the previous paragraph:

```
foreach order_detail {
    insert order_detail;
    get last_insert_id;
    foreach order_detail_addon {
        insert order_detail_addon with last_insert_id;
    }
}
```

---

*Edited to add:*

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and also see what the [PHP manual says about it](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

And you [should stop using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) the `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: sorry I dont get it...what you mean by "You need to insert the first row to table1 then the corresponding rows in table2; insert the second row to table1 then the corresponding rows in table2; etc."...How to do that please?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and yeah you get what I mean but the problem lies in displaying the addon items details indeed.Thats why I used the above foreach loop. But I'm just lost!

Comment: What do you mean by '...the problem lies in displaying the addon items details...'? Your question is about inserting items to the database, not retrieving them.